# Combining Google proto buffers with Jersey/JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, protocol-buffers

Currently I have a RESTful web service with endpoints that are exposed via Jersey/JAX-RS:

```
@Path("/widgets")
public class WidgetResource {
    @GET
    List<Widget> getAllWidgets() {
        // gets Widgets somehow
    }

    @POST
    Widget save(Widget w) {
        // Save widget and return it
    }
}
```

I use Jackson for serializing/deserializing my POJOs into JSON, and my service both responds to and sends back my POJOs as `application/json`.

I am now looking to possibly use Google protocol buffers (or an equivalent technology) to help compress/optimize the communication between client and service, as JSON/text is pretty bulky/wasteful.

In reality, I have a large backend that consists of a "microservice" architecture; dozens of REST services communicating with each other; this is why I'm looking to optimize the the messages sent backk and forth between all of them.

So I ask: is it possible to still have Jersey/JAX-RS serve up my service endpoints, but to gut out the Jackson/JSON stuff and replace it with Google protocol buffers? If so, what might this code look like?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

JAX-RS uses implementations of [`MessageBodyReader`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html) and [`MessageBodyWriter`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) to serialize/deserialize to and from differen media types. You can read more at [JAX-RS Entity Providers](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html). You can write your own to handle the serializion/derialization of your protobuf objects. Then just register the provider(s) with the application, either explicitly or implicitly through discovery.

### Example

**`widgets.proto`**

```
package widget;

option java_package = "protobuf.example";
option java_outer_classname = "WidgetsProtoc";

message Widget {
    required string id = 1;
    required string name = 2;
}

message WidgetList {
    repeated Widget widget = 1;
}
```

When this is compiled, I will be left with a `WidgetsProtoc` class with static inner `Widget` and `WidgetList` classes.

**`WidgetResource`**

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import protobuf.example.WidgetsProtoc.Widget;
import protobuf.example.WidgetsProtoc.WidgetList;

@Path("/widgets")
public class WidgetResource {
    
    @GET
    @Produces("application/protobuf")
    public Response getAllWidgets() {
        Widget widget1 = 
                Widget.newBuilder().setId("1").setName("widget 1").build();
        Widget widget2 = 
                Widget.newBuilder().setId("2").setName("widget 2").build();
        WidgetList list = WidgetList.newBuilder()
                .addWidget(widget1).addWidget(widget2).build();
        return Response.ok(list).build();
    }
    
    @POST
    @Consumes("application/protobuf")
    public Response postAWidget(Widget widget) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Saving Widget \n");
        builder.append("ID: ").append(widget.getId()).append("\n");
        builder.append("Name: ").append(widget.getName()).append("\n");
        return Response.created(null).entity(builder.toString()).build();
    }
}
```

You'll notice the use of the `"application/protobuf"` media type. This isn't a [standard media type](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), but there is a [draft in the working](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-rfernando-protocol-buffers-00). Also the [Guava library has define this media type as `MediaType.PROTOBUF`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/net/MediaType.html#PROTOBUF), which translates to `"application/protobuf"`, so I chose to stick with *that*.

**`MessageBodyReader` and `MessageBodyWriter`** all defined in one class. You can choose to do it separately. Makes no difference.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyWriter;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import protobuf.example.WidgetsProtoc.Widget;
import protobuf.example.WidgetsProtoc.WidgetList;

@Provider
@Produces("application/protobuf")
@Consumes("application/protobuf")
public class WidgetProtocMessageBodyProvider 
                   implements MessageBodyReader, MessageBodyWriter {

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class type, Type type1, 
            Annotation[] antns, MediaType mt) {
        return Widget.class.isAssignableFrom(type) 
                || WidgetList.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public Object readFrom(Class type, Type type1, Annotation[] antns, 
            MediaType mt, MultivaluedMap mm, InputStream in) 
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        if (Widget.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            return Widget.parseFrom(in);
        } else if (WidgetList.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            return WidgetList.parseFrom(in);
        } else {
            throw new BadRequestException("Can't Deserailize");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class type, Type type1, 
            Annotation[] antns, MediaType mt) {
        return Widget.class.isAssignableFrom(type) 
                || WidgetList.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(Object t, Class type, Type type1, 
            Annotation[] antns, MediaType mt) {  return -1; }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Object t, Class type, Type type1, 
            Annotation[] antns, MediaType mt, 
            MultivaluedMap mm, OutputStream out) 
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        if (t instanceof Widget) {
            Widget widget = (Widget)t;
            widget.writeTo(out);
        } else if (t instanceof WidgetList) {
            WidgetList list = (WidgetList)t;
            list.writeTo(out);
        }
    }  
}
```

**`TestCase`** (Make sure the provider is registered both with the server and client)

```
@Test
public void testGetIt() {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080/api");
    // Get all list
    WidgetList list = target.path("/widgets").request().get(WidgetList.class);
    System.out.println("===== Response from GET =====");
    for (Widget widget: list.getWidgetList()) {
        System.out.println("id: " + widget.getId() 
                         + ", name: " + widget.getName());
    }
    
    // Post one 
    Widget widget = Widget.newBuilder().setId("10")
                          .setName("widget 10").build();
    Response responseFromPost = target.path("widgets").request()
            .post(Entity.entity(widget, "application/protobuf"));
    System.out.println("===== Response from POST =====");
    System.out.println(responseFromPost.readEntity(String.class));
    responseFromPost.close();
}
```

Result:

```
===== Response from GET =====
id: 1, name: widget 1
id: 2, name: widget 2
===== Response from POST =====
Saving Widget 
ID: 10
Name: widget 10
```

Comment: Thanks @peeskillet (+1 !!!) Awesome answer! Quick followup: can you attest (perhaps from personal experience) that the network/bandwidth/performance gains of going with Protobug (vs JSON) are worth this implementation? Thanks again!

Comment: Unfortunately I have never really used protobuf (just dabbled with it here and there), so I don't have any real insight on performance gains :-( I thought maybe you have, that's why you raised the question :-)

Comment: @peeskillet How do you register the provider with the server and client?

Comment: @SambitTripathy if you are package scanning it should be automatically registered. Otherwise it depends on your app configuration. With Java config (with Jersey), you can just call register. Other than that I would need to know more information about your environment. There are many ways to register a provider

Comment: @peeskillet I am package scanning it. Media Type "application/protobuf" is somehow is not getting identified as I am not using the Guava library. Which version of guava did you use?

Comment: @N.M.N The reader and writer handle the (de)serialization for you behind the scenes. You just need to make sure it is registered either with the client or with the server side app.

Comment: Sorry what I meant was Client,Sorry. Any points on how Client calls these end points

Comment: @N.M.N The writer and reader are used for the client also. Look at my example and try to understand it. I haven't use Protobuf in a while so I forgot how everything works. All I have is this complete example that I put together to answer this question. Look at the documentation links if you are unsure about anything. Make sure to register the provider with the client.

Comment: To any future readers, Guava has nothing to do with anything. I just brought it up because of the name they used for the media type of Protobuf data, which is "application/protobuf". There needs to be an agreed upon name for the media type in order to do the [content negotiation (conneg)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation) dance. So you don't need Guava

Comment: I got: 
 error: package protobuf.example.WidgetsProtoc does not exist