# Why not serialize my protobuf?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

my widgets.proto:

```
option java_package = "example";
option java_outer_classname = "WidgetsProtoc";

message Widget {
required string name = 1;
required int32  id = 2;
}

message WidgetList {
repeated Widget widget = 1;
}
```

my rest: (Path: /widgets)

```
@GET
@Produces("application/x-protobuf")
public WidgetsProtoc.WidgetList getAllWidgets() {
    Widget widget1 =
            Widget.newBuilder().setId(1).setName("testing").build();
    Widget widget2 =
            Widget.newBuilder().setId(100).setName("widget 2").build();
    System.err.println("widgets1: " + widget1);
    System.err.println("widgets2: " + widget2);
    WidgetsProtoc.WidgetList list = WidgetsProtoc.WidgetList.newBuilder().addWidget(widget1).addWidget(widget2).build();
    System.err.println("list: " + list.toByteArray());


    return list;
}
```

And when i use postman i get this response:

```
(emptyline)    
(emptyline)
testing
(emptyline)
widget 2d
```

This is normal? I think  not really...in my messagebodywriter class i override writeto like this:

```
@Override
public void writeTo(WidgetsProtoc.WidgetList widgetList, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
    entityStream.write(widgetList.toByteArray());
}
```

I thought its good to send a byte array...but it is a little bit weird that not serialize nothing....or just my be the id...Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Are you sure this mediatype is right? What happens if you do @Produces("application/octet-stream") instead?

Comment: the same if i write to octet-stream

Comment: Are you using any frameworks? What's taking care of serialization of the WidgetsProtoc.WidgetList?

Comment: Finally figured you are actually using Jersey.
From what I see in other questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27092387/combining-google-proto-buffers-with-jersey-jax-rs/27099842#27099842
those GET methods actually return a Response, like: return Response.ok(list).build();

Comment: Here also the same problem...response is the same :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It already is in binary.
Have you noticed that you message consists of name and id but you get only name displayed?
That's what I get displayed when I just save the response as a "test" file from the browser's GET call:

```
$ cat test 



testing


widget 2d%
```

You can see cat being barely able to display it, but there is more content into it.

Now if I open it in bless (hex editor in ubuntu) I can get more out of it

```
0A 0B 0A 07 74 65 73 74 69 6E 67 10 01 0A 0C 0A 08 77 69 64 67 65 74 20 32 10 64
```

In general I wouldn't trust Postman to display binary data. You need to know how to decode it, and apparently Postman doesn't.

And here's the final proof:

```
$ cat test | protoc --decode_raw
1 {
  1: "testing"
  2: 1
}
1 {
  1: "widget 2"
  2: 100
}
```

Comment: waoooh....thanks...i download a hex editor for Windows and yes.... :) I dont think that it is binary already... thank you :)