# MediaType for ProtoBuf

Tags: java, jax-rs, protocol-buffers, prototype, mime-types

I need to send protobuf data to my end point from a client I created. Below is the code for the Client and JAXRS endpoint.

```
--client
Client genClient = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target2 = genClient.target("http://localhost:8080/ClientJAXRS/rest/Hello").path("/proto");
 String inputproto = String.format("\n" +  "syntax = \"proto3\";\n" + 
                "message Struct1 {\n" + 
                " string   s1Att1 = 1;\n" + 
                " int32    s1Att2 = 2;\n" + 
                " int32    s1Att3 = 3;\n" + 
                " Struct2  s1Att4 = 4;\n" + 
                " message Struct2 {\n" + 
                " repeated string s2Att1 = 1;\n" + 
                "  }\n" + 
                 + " ");
Response res =  target2.request("application/x-protobuf").put(Entity.text(inputproto));

--endpoint
@PUT
@Path("/proto")
@Consumes("application/x-protobuf")
//@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getInfo(String text){



  return    Response.ok(text.getBytes(),MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).status(200).build();
}
```

the output I get for this is Unsupported MediaType.

```
context=ClientResponse{method=PUT, uri=http://localhost:8080/ClientJAXRS/rest/Hello/proto, status=415, reason=Unsupported Media Type}}
```

Help me with the MIME TYPE for proto or the proto format that send.

### Edit 2 :

I made a file separate for protobuf  in data.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
 option java_outer_classname = "DataProtos";
 option java_package = "com.client.JAXClient";
 message Album {
     optional string title = 1;
     repeated string artist = 2;
     repeated int32 release_year = 3;
     required string song_title = 4;
 }
```

Generated the code for it in java using protoc -I  code and got Album class generated.

Implemented MessagebodyWriter and MessageBodyReader for it   as given below

```
@Provider
@Produces("application/x-protobuf")
@Consumes("application/x-protobuf")
public class ProtoMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Album>,MessageBodyReader<Album> {

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return type == Album.class ;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Album t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream out)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            Writer writer = new PrintWriter(out);
            t.writeTo(out);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return type == Album.class ;
    }

    @Override
    public Album readFrom(Class<Album> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream in)
            throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            return Album.parseFrom(in);
    }

}
```

Added 2 end points for protobuf as below

```
@GET
@Path("/proto-data")
@Consumes("application/x-protobuf")
 public Response getInfo(Album inpAlbum){
                   StringBuilder sbuilder = new  StringBuilder("Input album");
                   sbuilder.append("ID: ").append(inpAlbum.getReleaseYear()).append("\n");
                   sbuilder.append("Name: ").append(inpAlbum.getArtist()).append("\n");
                    return Response.created(null).entity(sbuilder.toString()).build();

}
```

I am trying to hit these endpoints from Client using

```
Response response =null;
Client client =null;
client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target2 = client.target("http://localhost:8081/ClientJAXRS/rest/Hello").path("/proto-data");
response= target2.request().get();
System.out.println(response);
```

But the response is

```
ClientJAXRS/rest/Hello/proto-data, status=500, reason=Internal Server Error}}
text/html;charset=utf-
```

Comment: You need to create a provider to handle that data type. Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27092387/2587435)

Comment: You basically just produce some text and send it to your client. This is not protobuf data. You need to do a transformation. You need to work on the protobuf basics before you try to establish client-server communication. I am not much of help, because I don't know protobuf, but this looks like an easy introduction: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers
The "MediaType" is NOT your problem.

Comment: 1) You need to understand the difference between `@Produces` and `@Consumes`. 2) The values of those annotations need to match for the provider _and_ the methods. The methods you're using a/x-protobuf while the provider your using a/protobuf.

Comment: Also when you make client GET requests, always set the Accept header and when you make POST/PUT requests always set the Content-Type header for the data-type you're sending.

Answer (score 1):

you can use *application/x-protobuf*

OkHttp request body sample:

```
final RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/x-protobuf"), builder.build().toByteArray());
```